# If $b$ is algebraic over a finite extension $K$ of $F$ then $[K(b):K]\mid [F(b):F]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

In *A Book of Abstract Algebra* by Charles C. Pinter, part 3 of exercise F page 299 is the following: ($a\mid b$ means $a$ divides $b$)

> Let $F$ be a field, and $K$  a finite extension of $F$. *Prove each of the following :*
>
> 3. If $b$ is algebraic over $K$, then $[K(b):K]\mid [F(b):F]$. (Hint: The minimal polynomial of $b$ over $F$ may factor in $K[x]$, and $b$ will then be a root of one of its irreducible factors.)

I couldn't solve this exercise. If $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ are the minimal polynomials of $b$ over, respectively, $F$ and $K$, then as $p(b)=0$ and $p(x)\in K[x]$, we have $q(x)\mid p(x)$, which shows that $[K(b):K]\le [F(b):F]$. But I wasn't able to show that it divides it. I tried using the different formulas like $[K(b):F]=[K(b):F(b)][F(b):F]$ but I wasn't able to reach the desired conclusion. I also tried using the fact that $\{1,b,\dots,b^{n-1}\}$ is a basis of the vector space $K(b)$ over $K$, and see how this can relate with $F(b)$ over $F$; that linearly independent family doesn't necessarily span $F(b)$ over $F$. I tried using the fact that $K=F(a_1,\dots,a_m)$ since it is a finite extension of $F$, but I didn't manage to reach the conclusion.

Would you help me please? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This claim seems to be false.

Let $\sqrt[3]{2}$ be the real cube root of $2$, and let $\zeta$ be a primitive cube root of unity, so that $\sqrt[3]{2}$, $\zeta \sqrt[3]{2}$ and $\zeta^2 \sqrt[3]{2}$ are the three roots of $X^3-2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Then $[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta\sqrt[3]{2}):\mathbb{Q}] = 3$, but $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}, \zeta\sqrt[3]{2}):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})]=2.$

Taking $F=\mathbb{Q}$, $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ and $b=\zeta\sqrt[3]{2}$, we seem to have a counter-example.

Comment: what if we require $K$ to be a normal extension of $F$ ?

Comment: When $K$ is normal over $F$, then the claim is true.

Comment: @i707107 well I always have problems with that. can you show me the argument ?

Comment: If $K$ is normal over $F$, then the minimal polynomial for $b$ over $F$ factors into irreducible polynomials over $K$ all of the same degree.

Comment: @i707107 sorry not clear to me. if $K$ is normal over $F$, then $b \in K$ and $[K(b):K] = 1$, or  $b \not \in K$ and $[K(b):K] = [F(b):F]$ ?

Comment: @user1952009 See my answer. Note that $b\in K$ is not assumed.

Comment: no ok, taking $F = \mathbb{Q}$, $K = \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{3})$, $b= \zeta_{15}$ I can see this is not true, and I see what you mean with "irreducible polynomials all of the same degree". @i707107

Comment: Amazing! Thank you very much for your answer!

Answer (score 5):

A counterexample of OP's statement is already given by @Pierre-Guy Plamondon.

**With normality assumption for $K$ over $F$**

Suppose $K$ is normal over $F$. Let $f$ be a minimal polynomial for $b$ over $F$. Then we will prove that $f$ factors into irreducible polynomials over $K$ all of the same degree.

Note that OP pointed out the degree of the minimal polynomial for $b$ over $K$ is the degree of field extension $[K(b):K]$. Let $b'$ be any root of $f$ in $\overline{K}$. Let $\sigma : K(b) \rightarrow \overline{K}$ be an embedding fixing $F$ with $\sigma(b)=b'$. We claim that $[K(b'):K]=[K(b):K]$.

To do this, note that $\sigma:K(b)\rightarrow \overline{K}$ is an injective $F$-linear mapping. Since $K$ is normal over $F$, the restriction $\sigma|_K$ is an automorphism of $K$ fixing $F$.  Thus, $\sigma(K(b))= K(b')$. This shows $K(b)$ and $K(b')$ are isomorphic as $F$-vector spaces via an $F$-linear isomorphism $\sigma$. This shows that $[K(b):F]=[K(b'):F]$. Hence, we have
$$
[K(b):K][K:F]=[K(b):F]=[K(b'):F]=[K(b'):K][K:F].
$$
It follows that $[K(b):K]=[K(b'):K]$. Thus, the irreducible factors of the minimal polynomial for $b$ over $F$ must factor into the irreducible polynomials over $K$ all of the same degree.

Therefore, we have $[K(b):K] | [F(b):F]$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Normality isn't introduced yet up to the chapter I reached, but it's very soothing to know that the exercise is true with an additional assumption. I'll try solving this exercise again after studying it!