# The splitting field of $p(x)=x^4+ax^2+b$ over $F$ is $F[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, roots, extension-field, splitting-field

In *A Book of Abstract Algebra* by Charles C. Pinter, part 5 of exercise C page 318 is the following:

> If $p(x)=x^4+ax^2+b\in F[x]$, then $F[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle$ is the root field of $p(x)$ over $F$.

(The root field is the splitting field)

We should of course assume that $p(x)$ is irreducible over $F$ lest $F[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle$ wouldn't be an integral domain. Assuming this, we have $F[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle\cong F(m)$ for any root $m$ of $p(x)$ in an extension of $K$. As $\deg p(x)=4$, we have $[F(m):F]=4$ for any root $m$ of $p(x)$.

Let $\Delta=a^2-4b$, $m=\sqrt{\frac{-a-\sqrt{\Delta}}{2}}$ and $n=\sqrt{\frac{-a+\sqrt{\Delta}}{2}}$. Then $m$, $-m$, $n$ and $-n$ are the distinct roots of $p(x)$. Thus, to show that $F(m)$ is the splitting field of $p(x)$, it is enough to show that $n\in F(m)$. That's what I'm unable to show.

$F(m)$ is a $4$-dimensional vector space over $F$ and $\{1,m,m^2,m^3\}$ is a basis of it. We have $\sqrt{\Delta}=-a-2m^2\in F(m)$ and $n^2=-a-m^2\in F(m)$. If $n\in F(m)$ then $\exists !\,x,y,z,t\in F,\, n=x+ym+zm^2+tm^3$. Using the equality $p(m)=0$, we find, unless there's an error, that $$n^2=x^2+abt^2-(2ty+z^2)b+2(xy-btz)m+((a^2-b)t^2+y^2+2xz-a(tz+z^2))m^2+2(tx-atz+yz)m^3$$ leading to a pretty complicated nonlinear system: $$\begin{cases} x^2+abt^2-(2ty+z^2)b &= &-a \\ 2(xy-btz) &= &0 \\ (a^2-b)t^2+y^2+2xz-a(tz+z^2) &= &-1 \\ 2(tx-atz+yz) &= &0\end{cases} $$ (we don't even know what is the caracteristic of this field).

This suggests that there might be another method, but I couldn't find anything. Would you please help me? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Chapter, section, page...?

Comment: Ok, found it...and Charles Pinter seems to be the one and only individual in this side of the Galaxy to call "root field" to what everyone else calls "splitting field" .

Comment: Oops sorry for being late. I always indicate the page, but I forgot to write it here. Haha well I didn't study field theory in any other book so I didn't know he's the only one who calls them root fields. Thank you, I'll edit my post.

Comment: @Vik78 You just deleted your answer. If your answer requires additional assumptions, can you bring it back? There are several exercises in *A Book of Abstract Algebra* that are false, sometimes unless a new assumption is added as in [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1915525/if-b-is-algebraic-over-a-finite-extension-k-of-f-then-kbk-mid-fb)

Comment: No, I realized my answer was wrong. Still working on it. I'm assuming that the polynomial is separable and characteristic is not 2 so I can use quadratic formula/Galois groups.

Comment: If you're still trying, though, I think a less direct method will be a little more productive. That system of equations looks pretty intractable. I think there's probably a quick way to do this but haven't found it yet. I'm looking over the chapter now and it appears he assumes fields have characteristic zero, which implies the assumptions I was working with.

Comment: Ah ok. Yeah unfortunately I coudln't find an inderect method.

Comment: Just got a downvote. Would the downvoter explain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is false in general. As a counterexample I proffer the case $F=\Bbb{Q}$ and
$$p(x)=x^4-2.$$

It is irreducible by Eisenstein. But its splitting field cannot be gotten by adjoining one of the zeros. The zero $\root4\of2$ is real, and obviously won't generate the non-real roots.

More precisely, the splitting field is $K=\Bbb{Q}(\root4\of2,i)$. We easily see that $[K:\Bbb{Q}]=8$. It is not hard to show that the Galois group is isomorphic to the dihedral group $D_4$ of order eight. (I'm fairly sure this has been done on our site)

---

OTOH, if $F$ is finite, then the claim is true. This is because any finite extension of a finite field is Galois (actually cyclic).